# mysql find location of row

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database full of users scores for a game I created. I'm trying to add a feature to show the user what their current rank is.

I need a query that will sort the rows by score DESC and then locate the users score and get his / her rank by their username.

I know it's a pretty simple query, but my mind just isn't working right now.

```
CREATE TABLE HighScores(
   id       int(11)      NOT NULL auto_increment
  ,deviceID varchar(100) NOT NULL
  ,username varchar(50)  NOT NULL
  ,score    varchar(10)  NOT NULL
  ,game     int(2)       NOT NULL
  ,spins    int(10)      NOT NULL
  ,PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `HighScores` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `deviceID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `score` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `game` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `spins` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i don't know your table structure it's hard to come up with a query.

[This article](http://jimlife.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/) does exactly what you want.

Example query:

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘rank’, p.* from player p, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r order by score desc limit 10;
```

The magic is in the variable rownum, which is a variable incremented for each row.

Comment: Why is this an accepted answer? It doesn't do what was asked: it doesn't give a position in ranking for specific username

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a table structure like this:

```
create table users(
   user_id
  ,score    int
  ,primary key(user_id)
);
```

You can calculate the rank for a user by counting the number of users with a lower score.

```
select user_id
      ,score
      ,(select count(*) + 1 from users x where u.score < x.score) as rank
  from users u
 where u.user_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @rank:= 0;
SELECT rank, score FROM (
                    SELECT @rank:= @rank + 1 AS rank, id, score
                    FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC
                    ) as result WHERE id=xxx;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @rank=0;

SELECT username, rank
FROM (
  SELECT username, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank
  FROM HighScores 
  ORDER BY score DESC
) AS t
WHERE username = :username
```